# Kubernetes Ingress Whitelist IP for path

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I know I can whitelist IPs for the entire ingress object, but is there a way to whitelist IPs for individual paths?  For example, if I only want to allow `/admin` to be accessed from `10.0.0.0/16`?

`ingress.yml`:

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontend
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: frontend
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "10.0.0.0/16"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - frontend.example.com
      secretName: frontend-tls
  rules:
    - host: frontend.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: frontend
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /api
            backend:
              serviceName: api
              servicePort: 8000
          - path: /admin
            backend:
              serviceName: api
              servicePort: 8000
          - path: /staticfiles
            backend:
              serviceName: api
              servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 8):

If you would like to split it two Ingres, it would look like example below. First `Ingress` with `/admin` path and annotation and second `Ingress` with others `paths` allowed by any `IP`.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontend-admin
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: frontend
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "10.0.0.0/16"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - frontend.example.com
      secretName: frontend-tls
  rules:
    - host: frontend.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /admin
            backend:
              serviceName: api
              servicePort: 8000
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontend-all
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: frontend
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - frontend.example.com
      secretName: frontend-tls
  rules:
    - host: frontend.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: frontend
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /api
            backend:
              serviceName: api
              servicePort: 8000
          - path: /staticfiles
            backend:
              serviceName: api
              servicePort: 80
```

Please keep in mind that annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "10.0.0.0/16"` will override some of your config. As mentioned in [Nginx docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#whitelist-source-range):

> Adding an annotation to an Ingress rule overrides any global restriction.

Another option is to use `ConfigMap` [whitelist-source-range](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#whitelist-source-range). Like mentioned in [this example](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html), you can use `ngx_http_access_module`.

As in Nginx config, each `path` is saved as

```
location / {
  ...
}

location /api {
  ...
}
```

you can add thoses restrictions there. Below example:

```
location / {
    deny  192.168.1.1;
    allow 192.168.1.0/24;
    allow 10.1.1.0/16;
    allow 2001:0db8::/32;
    deny  all;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try deviding the ingress in parts. i created two ingress both having diff. path and you can change whitelisting IP

**1** :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontend
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: frontend
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "10.0.0.0/16"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - frontend.example.com
      secretName: frontend-tls
  rules:
    - host: frontend.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: frontend
              servicePort: 80
```

**2** :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontend
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: frontend
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "10.0.0.0/16"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - frontend.example.com
      secretName: frontend-tls
  rules:
    - host: frontend.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: frontend-two
              servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you resolve the issue? I can't figure out, how to use this option, from the previous answer

> Another option is to use ConfigMap whitelist-source-range. Like
>   mentioned in this example, you can use ngx_http_access_module

Can you provide example, please?

Dividing to several ingresses - it's very unsuitable for some cases =(

---

I've just find another solution (but i think solution from previous answer more pretty):
You can use annotation **nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet** and write, like directly in nginx.conf

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-snippet

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/

Comment: The best option I found was just to have 2 different ingress manifests, though I didn't have time to do much research after I got it working with 2 ingresses.