# How to allow multiple IPs only on ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, gke-networking

I have number of IPs and I want only to allow those IP into my ingress

I know I can do this with in my ingress annotations,

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: 10.0.0.0/16

But what I want is that I have multiple IPS and not only `10.0.0.0/16`
So If for example I have IPs like `178.1.0.2/17`,`10.0.0.0/16`,`178.2.0.3/18` and I only want to allow this IPs to my ingress then how can I acheive that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using [Nginx Ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) you can do it adding specific annotation `whitelist-source-range`.

[nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#whitelist-source-range)

> You can specify allowed client IP source ranges through the nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range annotation. The value is a comma separated list of CIDRs, e.g. 10.0.0.0/24,172.10.0.1.

To configure this setting globally for all Ingress rules, the whitelist-source-range value may be set in the NGINX ConfigMap.

**Also keep in mind that:**

> Adding an annotation to an Ingress rule overrides any global restriction.

Also if you would like to use `Ingress Whitelist IP for Path` you can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58925853/kubernetes-ingress-whitelist-ip-for-path/59052066).

**Example:**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontend
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: 10.0.0.0/16,178.2.0.3/18,178.1.0.2/17
spec:
  rules:
    - host: something.something.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /app1
            backend:
              serviceName: app1
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /api
            backend:
              serviceName: api
              servicePort: 8000

ingress.extensions/frontend created
```

Comment: what if i am not using nginx

Comment: Please specify why ingress you want to use. Default Kubernetes, default cloud ingress, traefik, etc? For example traefik is using [IPWhitelist](https://docs.traefik.io/middlewares/ipwhitelist/).