# Preserve client IP in GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress

I have a backend application behind an nginx ingress controller in a GKE cluster and I want to whitelist a certain IP only to access it. I added to the associated ingress this annotation:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "my-ip/32"
```

I also have the `externalTrafficPolicy` set to `Local` in the ingress controller service.

The issue is that when I hit my application it always return `403 Forbidden`
And in the ingress controller logs when I hit the application it logs `access forbidden by rule, client: 127.0.0.1, server: my-appliaction.domain.ext` which means that the client IP is not forwarded to the ingress controller.

Here is my Ingress manifest:

```html
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my_app
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: x.x.x.x/32
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: my_app.company.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: my_app
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - my_app.company.com
    secretName: certificate.tls
```

Did I miss something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll get better traction at serverfault.com, stackoverflow is for questions related to software development, not networking or system administration.

Answer (score 0):

**To preserve client IP in GKE we can follow the below 2 methods:**

**Method 1:** If you want to configure the client ip to all ingress rules, we have to set this ip globally and the whitelist-source-range value should be set in the NGINX ConfigMap in whitelist-source-range. You can use the [ngx_http_access_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html).

**Note:** All ingress-controllers will not support whitelisting, you can cross check your ingress-controller from this [document](https://blog.container-solutions.com/kubernetes-quick-tip).

**Method 2 :** If you don't want to configure the ip to all your ingress rules -  you need to create two separate ingresses. First ingress is  for white listing hosts and the second ingress is for your host.

For more information refer to this [Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58925853/kubernetes-ingress-whitelist-ip-for-path).

Regarding 403 Forbidden error
refer to this [Serverfault Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/390210).

Comment: I would like the whitelisting to be by ingress. Any example on how to use two separate ingresses? since I don't understand why two while I only want to whitelist a single IP... and finally isn't the annotation enough for whitelisting?

Comment: Try this similar [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70848466) may help to resolve your issue.